# mootools | Router plugin fires twice after updating to the latest mootools version

Tags: javascript, hash, mootools

I have update my mootools version to the latest one. The latest version of mootools is 1.5.1. After update this router mootools plugin fires twice. Before update it works like a charm.
Where is a problem? Router code has been posted below:

```
;(function() { 

    var hc = 'hashchange',
        hcSupported = !!(('on' + hc) in window),
        eventHosts = [window, document],
        getQueryString = function(queryString) {

            var result = {};

            queryString.replace(/([^=&]+)=([^&]*)/g, function(m, key, value) {

                if (key.search("\\[\\]") !== -1) {

                    var new_key = key.substring(0, key.length - 2);

                    typeof result[decodeURIComponent(new_key)] === 'undefined' ? result[decodeURIComponent(new_key)] = [decodeURIComponent(value)] : result[decodeURIComponent(new_key)].push(decodeURIComponent(value));
                } else {
                    result[decodeURIComponent(key)] = decodeURIComponent(value);
                }
            }); 
            return result;
        };

    Element.Events.hashchange = {
        onAdd: function () {
            var hash = location.hash,
                check = function () {
                    if (hash == location.hash)
                        return;

                    hash = location.hash;
                    eventHosts.invoke('fireEvent', hc, hash.indexOf('#') == 0 ? hash.substr(1) : hash);
                };
            (hcSupported && (window.onhashchange = check)) || check.periodical(10000);
        }
    };


    // Router
    this.Router = new Class({

        Implements: [Options, Events],

        options: {
            triggerOnLoad : true // check route on load
        },

        routes: {
            // '#!path/:query/:id?': 'eventname',
        },

        boundEvents: {},

        initialize: function(options) {
            var self = this;

            this.setOptions(options);
            this.options.routes && (this.routes = this.options.routes);

            window.addEvent(hc, function(e) {
                var hash = location.hash,
                    path = hash.split('?')[0],
                    query = hash.split('?')[1] || '',
                    notfound = true,
                    route;

                for(route in self.routes) {
                    var keys = [],
                        regex = self.normalize(route, keys, true, false),
                        found = regex.exec(path),
                        routeEvent = false;

                    if (found) {
                        notfound = false;
                        self.req = found[0];

                        var args = found.slice(1),
                            param = {};

                        Array.each(args, function(a, i) {
                            typeof keys[i] !== 'undefined' && (param[keys[i].name] = a);
                        });

                        self.route = route;
                        self.param = param || {};
                        self.query = query && getQueryString(query);


                        // find referenced events
                        routeEvent = self.routes[route];

                        // generic before route, pass route id, if avail
                        self.fireEvent('before', routeEvent);

                        // if there is an identifier and an event added
                        if (routeEvent && self.$events[routeEvent]) {
                            // route event was defined, fire specific before pseudo
                            self.fireEvent(routeEvent + ':before');
                            // call the route event handler itself, pass params as arguments
                            self.fireEvent(routeEvent, Object.values(self.param));
                        }
                        else {
                            // requested route was expected but not found or event is missing
                            self.fireEvent('error', ['Route', routeEvent, 'is undefined'].join(' '));
                        }

                        // fire a generic after event
                        self.fireEvent('after', routeEvent);

                        // if route is defined, also fire a specific after pseudo
                        routeEvent && self.fireEvent(routeEvent + ':after');
                        break;
                    }
                }

                notfound && self.fireEvent('undefined');

            });

            this.fireEvent('ready');
            this.options.triggerOnLoad && window.fireEvent(hc);
        },

        navigate: function(route, trigger) {
            if (location.hash == route && trigger) {
                window.fireEvent(hc);
            }
            else {
                location.hash = route;
            }
        },

        normalize: function(path, keys, sensitive, strict) {
            // normalize by https://github.com/visionmedia/express
            if (path instanceof RegExp) return path;

            path = path.concat(strict ? '' : '/?').replace(/\/\(/g, '(?:/').replace(/(\/)?(\.)?:(\w+)(?:(\(.*?\)))?(\?)?/g, function(_, slash, format, key, capture, optional) {

                keys.push({
                    name: key,
                    optional: !! optional
                });

                slash = slash || '';

                return [
                    (optional ? '' : slash),
                    '(?:',
                    (optional ? slash : ''),
                    (format || '') + (capture || (format && '([^/.]+?)' || '([^/]+?)')) + ')',
                    (optional || '')
                ].join('');
            }).replace(/([\/.])/g, '\\$1').replace(/\*/g, '(.*)');


            return new RegExp('^' + path + '$', sensitive ? '' : 'i');
        }
    });
}());
```

Comment: haha shit. this is partly my code. https://github.com/epitome-mvc/Epitome/blob/master/src/epitome-router.js - which is supported by XRado in its own git repo - see https://github.com/xrado/Router and raise an issue, if possible - highlighting __what fires twice__ and steps to reproduce it.

Comment: Yes. It's your plugin.

Comment: wonder if it happens in the mootools-free ver here. https://github.com/DimitarChristoff/epik/blob/master/lib/router.js

Comment: that's part of a mvc framework, not meant to be used as is - can you just build an example of the problem on jsfiddle.net instead? i will have a look